# How to combine bson.M filters

Tags: mongodb, go, filter

I am trying to combine some filters with no success. I am using the mongodb driver for go

```
// FindOneByID returns an error on fail, otherwise, it sets the {out} by the result.
func FindOneByID(collectionName string, id *primitive.ObjectID, out interface{}, considerArchivedItems bool) error {
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
    var filter bson.M

    if considerArchivedItems {
        filter = bson.M{"_id": id}
    } else {
        filter = bson.M{"$and": bson.A{ bson.M{"_id": id}, bson.M{isArchived: bson.M{"$ne": false}}}}
    }

    return database.Collection(collectionName).FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(out)
}
```

Now, I insert an object as archived and trying to get the document. The document is inserted as archived, so I want to consider archived items.

However, when I pass in the `else`, document can be either archived or not (`false` or `true`), I still get it anyway. So it means that my $and doesn’t work..

```
const (
    databaseNameUnitTests           = "database_name_unit_tests"
    databaseCollectionNameUnitTests = "database_name_unit_tests"
)

type Test struct {
    ID          *primitive.ObjectID `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    IsArchived  bool                `protobuf:"varint,2,opt,name=IsArchived,proto3" json:"is_archived,omitempty" bson:"is_archived,omitempty"`
    Description string              `protobuf:"varint,3,opt,name=Description,proto3" json:"description,omitempty" bson:"description,omitempty"`
}

// func
    var item Test
    err := mongodb.FindOneByID(databaseCollectionNameUnitTests, insertedID, &item, false)
```

The following query from Robo 3T : `db.getCollection('database_name_unit_tests').find({$and:[{"_id":ObjectId("5d2e8afeb0e106fbe0d5af21")},{"is_archived": {$ne:false}}]})`
this works tho, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a lot of trouble getting bson.A to work with $and statements, try using bson.D instead.

```
bson.D{{"$and", []bson.D{
   bson.D{{"_id",id}},
   bson.D{{"isArchived", bson.D{{"$ne", false}}}},
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

$or Evaluates one or more expressions and returns true if any of the expressions are true

```
    filter = bson.M{"$or": bson.A{ bson.M{"_id": id}, bson.M{isArchived: bson.M{"$ne": false}}}}
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/or/